# Find Extreme Value in Integers Given

Tags: c++

I'm trying to find the highest value in a given list, but in an input list like this

`7 385 -390 305 470 -145 255 30`

my output is wrong, `385` instead of `470`.

Could anyone please guide me towards my error!

Task description:

> Read in an input value for variable numIn. Then, read numIn integers from input and output the largest of the integers read. End with a newline.
>
> Ex: If the input is 2 345 -5, then the output is:
>
> 345

*my code below*

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int numIn;

    int high = 0;

    cin >> numIn;

    for (int i = 0; i < numIn; i++) {
        cin >> numIn;

        if (numIn > high) {
            high = numIn;
        }
    }

    cout << high << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger?

Comment: No I have not since I work through my digital textbook's IDE.

Comment: Then I would recommend a proper IDE with a debugger, there are even online ones nowadays, you will not be a good developer if you cannot debug. Seeing what your code actually does also helps a lot with the learning itself.

Comment: I will definitely start using a debugger from now on! Thank you for the information!

Comment: Yea, it will help you a lot in your classes chasing the various issues or typos. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your list has negative numbers. You can't set the default value of `high` to `0` since a list with all negative numbers won't work if you do this.

The error in your loop occurs because **you overwrite `numIn`**. Use a different variable for the number of input numbers.

```cpp
cin >> numIn; // numIn is the number of input numbers
  for (int i = 0; i < numIn; i++) {
    cin >> numIn; // oops, numIn is now the first input number. it has been overwritten.
    if (numIn > high) {
      high = numIn;
    }
  }
```

A correct solution would look like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  int N; // assume that N >= 1. You could also replace this with numIn.
  std::cin >> N;

  int max;
  std::cin >> max; // take in the first integer outside the loop
  for (auto i = 1; i < N; i++) { // loop which runs N - 1 times
    int E;
    std::cin >> E;
    max = std::max(max, E);
  }

  std::cout << max << '\n';
}
```

## Without using `std::max()`

If you don't want to use `std::max()`, replace the line where you use it with a normal comparison (this is what `std::max()` does internally too)

```cpp
if (E > max) { max = E; }
```

Comment: Hello @avighnac
I am currently doing these labs in Zybooks and since I haven't "learned" std::max my professor rather me not use it till later in the lessons. Is there anyway you could guide me by comparing the numbers through '>'?. Thank you for telling me to why negative numbers won't work!

Comment: @GabrielZuniga just edited my answer with this in mind.

Comment: I undeclared 0 from numIn and made a new variable to read through the list in my for loop and it completely solved the issue. Also thank you for editing my layout on my post (its obvious I really don't know what I am doing). Thanks for the help!

Comment: @GabrielZuniga no problem! If this solved your issue, you can go ahead and accept the answer.